# How to check if a variable is in an array and then have it equal something in that array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array like:

```
[{"tierId":0,"tierName":"Blue"},{"tierId":1,"tierName":"Green"}]
```

how do I check if my variable = `tierName` and if it does have it equal the `tierId`. So if my variable is `Green` I want the same variable to equal `1`. I tried:

```
$parsed = (array) json_decode($body->getContents()); 
if (in_array($start, $parsed)){
        $start == $parsed['tierId'];
    }
```

Comment: `in_array` can help you

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you explain it betteR?

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find the key to match with the variable you can use this array_key_exists() function. Like this below

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

And once the key match with your variable, you can also check if it is match with the value of that array key.

Also if you want to find a variable is exist or not into your array. You can use this in_array() function.

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Hope this will help you figure out solution.

Comment: He has a 2-dimensional array, so `array_key_exists` and `in_array` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function that searches a 2-dimensional array like that, you have to write a loop.

```
$parsed = json_decode($body->getContents(), true); // true makes it return arrays instead of objects
foreach ($parsed as $item) {
    if ($item['tierName' == $start) {
        $start = $item['tierId'];
        break;
    }
}
```